# How to add Custom welcome control menu item Icons SharePoint 2013?

Tags: image-rendition, welcome-page

Hi I have developed a custom welcome control for SharePoint 2013 website. I can see the Welcome control menu items as required but the Icons for each menu items are not visible. This is the code for each menu item.

`<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="Change_custom_Password"
                 Text="Change Password"
                 Description="Change my password."
                 ImageUrl="/images/changepassword.png"
                 OnLoad="MenuItemTemplate_OnLoad"
                 MenuGroupId="150"
                 UseShortId="true"
                 Sequence="110"
/>`

This code works fine in Sharepoint 2010 and displays the images next to the menu item but the ImageUrl property is not working in SP2013.

SP2013 looks like this:

[image: SP2013 looks like]

and SP2010 looks like this:

[image: SP2010 looks like]

Can anyone suggest how can I get this working in 2013?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this thing working through CSS in master page by using the ID of the menu item as follows:

```
div[id$="Change_custom_Password"]{
background-image:url('/SiteAssets/images/Change_custom_Password.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left ;  
width:100%;
height:32px;
}
```